# Pra que serve a classe SplStack?

Tags: php, spl

De acordo com o PHP:

> The SplStack class provides the main functionalities of a stack implemented using a doubly linked list.

Que quer dizer:

> A classe SplStack fornece as principais funcionalidades de uma pilha implementada usando uma lista duplamente ligada.

Embora o Manual do PHP tente oferecer alguns exemplos, nada fica muito claro (na maioria dos casos).

Isso me gera algumas dúvidas quando ao uso, já que não costumo ver nenhum programador PHP sair por aí dizendo: "Use a classe `SplStack` para fazer isso ou aquilo".

Então, na prática, para que eu poderia utilizar a classe `SplStack`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `SplStack` é uma classe da biblioteca padrão do PHP (SPL -> Standard PHP Library). Pertence ao grupo de estrutura de dados: http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

Sobre o que faz essa classe, o próprio nome já sugere. Stack é pilha (empilhamento de dados).

Essa classe age como um array reverso, onde os dados vão sendo empilhados, ao contrário de um array comum onde os dados recebem a posição seguinte.

Exemplo:

```
$stack = new SplStack();

$stack[] = 1;
$stack[] = 2;
$stack[] = 3;

foreach ($stack as $item)  {
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída no caso será:

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: Daniel, se importa se eu adicionar um exemplo (código) na sua resposta?

Comment: tudo bem...  a resposta nao é minha.. é da comunidade. Manda bala!