# Como criar e manipular listas em PHP?

Tags: php, lista

Em Java é possível criar e manipular lista de qualquer tipo de dado utilizando o `List<E>`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("Stack");
lista.add("Over");
lista.add("flow");
```

Criei uma lista de tipo `String` e adicionei três valores a ela através do método `add()`.

Em PHP existe algum recurso semelhante ao Java para manipulação e criação de listas?

Comment: Bem no PHP você consegue manipular uma lista, mais ou menos desse jeito ai, mas não vai conseguir restringir os tipos de dados que a lista vai receber.

Comment: Relacionada:[Trabalhar com listas sem ser usando Array() em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110132/28595)

Comment: Concordo com quase tudo que estão dizendo, mas, eu consigo sim criar uma enumeração sem `if` com tipo passado nos métodos (já acontecia isso em versão anteriores do PHP e agora fortemente na versão 7) com retorno também de um determinado tipo. Claro que não é `Generics` igual C# ou Java, mas, eu consigo criar a enumeração particular, que ao meu ver dependendo do caso não precisa, imagine criar um enumeração para cada `classe` seria ruim para o desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP não é uma linguagem com muita disciplina de tipos.

Em PHP existe um recurso chamado *array*. O *array* pode ser uma lista numerada ou indexada - e pode também ser as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo.

Por exemplo:

```
 $arr = [];

 $arr[] = "Stack";
 $arr[] = "Over";
 $arr[] = "Flow";
```

Resultado:

```
[
  "Stack",
  "Over",
  "Flow",
]
```

Nesse caso, a ordem do `array` não depende da numeração/nomeação que um índice recebe, e sim na ordem que são exibidos.

Então isso abaixo daria certo:

```
 $arr[98] = "Stack";
 $arr['96'] = "Over";
 $arr[97] = "Flow";


[
  98 => "Stack",
  96 => "Over",
  97 => "Flow",
]
```

## SplFixedArray - um recurso do SPL

Na minha opinião, o mecanismo do PHP mais próximo ao apresentando na pergunta é a classe `SplFixedArray`. Essa classe faz parte da biblioteca padrão do PHP, chamada [SPL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.spl.php). Com essa classe, é possível determinar um objeto com uma lista, com um número limitado de elementos.

Veja:

```
 $arr = new SplFixedArray(3);

 $arr[] = 1;
 $arr[] = 2;
 $arr[] = 3;
 $arr[] = 4; // Lança uma exceção, pois o número é limitado.
```

Mas, voltando novamente ao início dessa resposta, o recurso que você precisa seria o *array* mesmo. O `SplFixedArray` garante o limite de elementos que serão adicionados, mas não tem restrição de tipos.

## Você pode fazer uma implementação

No PHP existe duas interfaces especiais chamadas `ArrayAccess` e `Iterator`. Com essas duas, é possível criar uma classe, determinando o tipo de elementos que poderão ser adicionados à sua lista.

Veja um exemplo que montei para você:

```
class StringList implements ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $items = [];

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        if (is_string($value)) {

            $key ? $this->items[$key] = $value : array_push($this->items, $value);

            return $this;
        }

        throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Essa é uma lista que aceita somente string');
    }

    public function offsetGet($key)
    {
        return $this->items[$key];
    }

    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
        return isset($this->items[$key]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
        unset($this->items[$key]);
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->items);
    }
}
```

A utlização da classe seria assim:

```
$list = new StringList;
$list[] = 'Wallace';
$list[] = 'Maniero';
$list[] = 'Denner Carvalho';
$list[] = 1; // Se fizer isso vai lancar exceção

foreach ($list as $string) {
    var_dump($string);
}
```

Veja isso funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/uDv87p).

<sub>**Nota**: A classe criada acima é apenas um exemplo. Fica a critério de cada um como implementar algum recurso, porém eu não creio que seja viável fazer como exemplificado, já que o PHP é uma linguagem fracamente *tipada* (nada de sair dando uma de *master of OOP* ;) ).</sub>

**Ainda quer ir mais longe com isso?**

No PHP 7, existe um recurso que te permite definir o tipo do argumento de uma função. Combinando isso com o operador `ellipsis`, você pode fazer um "hack" para criar um *array* (estilo lista) com tipos específicos.

Veja:

```
function int_list(int ...$strings)
{
    return $strings;
}


int_list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Se você adicionasse uma `string` (que não fosse numérica), retornaria um erro:

```
int_list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'x');
```

Erro retornado:

> Argument 6 passed to int_list() must be of the type integer, string given

## Outros recursos disponíveis no SPL

Além de você poder implementar, o PHP também oferece alguns recursos novos, como a classe chamada [`SplObjectStorage`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splobjectstorage.php), que tem a finalidade de trabalhar com armazenamento de objetos.

Além do já citado, contamos também com:

- SplDoublyLinkedList
- SplStack
- SplQueue
- SplHeap
- SplMaxHeap
- SplMinHeap
- SplPriorityQueue
- SplFixedArray
- SplObjectStorage

Além dessa listinha aí, talvez seja importante citar sobre os [Generators](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50208/quais-as-vantagens-de-usar-um-generator-yield-no-php).

É claro que esses recursos jamais se compararão com uma linguagem *tipada*, como no caso do Java ou C#.

Leia mais:

- [Pra que serve a classe SplStack?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81109/pra-que-serve-a-classe-splstack)
- [The SplDoublyLinkedList class](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php)
- [Quais as vantagens de usar um "generator" (yield) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50208/quais-as-vantagens-de-usar-um-generator-yield-no-php)

Comment: Falou em SPL, morreu pra mim :D

Comment: @bigown concordo em parte, eu pessoalmente não uso, mas `spl_autoload` é quase fundamental XD PS: +1

Answer (score 9):

É o *array* normal mesmo. O *array* do PHP não é um *array* de verdade, como conhecemos em outras linguagens. Eles são listas por definição.

Lembre-se que PHP é uma linguagem de *script*, ela não foi feita para ter a melhor robustez e performance na aplicação das estruturas de dados. Entretanto isso dá grande flexibilidade e facilidade de uso. Java prefere o caminho de especialização para obter o melhor resultado.

PHP é uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada, e as estruturas permitem colocar qualquer coisa. Então se quer saber se tem como restringir que a lista só aceite *strings*. Não dá. Teria que ter algoritmos para garantir isso.

Claro que você pode criar uma classe para abstrair esse tratamento se quiser. Tudo será resolvido em tempo de execução (em PHP é sempre assim mesmo), ou seja, vai ter um `if` na hora de adicionar o elemento que verificará se é *string* para permitir a inclusão ou não. As implementações normalmente serão ingênuas e terão performance de `HashMap` e não de `Array`, como acontece em listas no Java. Mas em PHP ninguém liga para performance.

Exemplo:

```
$lista = [];
$lista[] = "Stack";
$lista[] = "Over";
$lista[] = "flow";
```

Há quem prefira com [`aray_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
$lista = array();
array_push($lista, "Stack");
array_push($lista, "Over");
array_push($lista, "flow");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NnTz5L). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vjegnyhn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/List.php).

Note que [o *array* do PHP pode assumir uma forma associativa](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), ou seja, pode se comportar como o `HashMap`, ou seja é um par de chave e valor. Você não tem muito controle sobre isso. Basta colocar um elemento que fuja de uma sequência e já é uma mapa.